# limits proof by induction

Tags: limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, induction

Let $ \{a_n\}_{n \geq 0},\{b_n\}_{n \geq 0}  $ be two sequences. The sequences are given as $ b_n:= \dfrac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}2 $ $a_n = \frac{c}{b_{n}} $ for $n \geq 1$ with $b_0 = b $ and $a_0 = \dfrac{c}{b}$.

I know that: $$ \frac{a_{0}+b_{0}}{2} > \sqrt{a_{0}b_{0}} $$

Now I want to prove that for all integers n: $$ a_n < \sqrt{c} < b_n  $$
I wanna prove this by induction over $n$.

For the base case: $n=1$

$$ a_1 = \frac{c}{b_{1}} = \frac{c}{0.5(a_{0}+b_{0})} < \frac{c}{\sqrt{a_{0}b_{0}}} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c}} = \sqrt{c} = \sqrt{a_{1}b_{1}} < {0.5(a_{1}+b_{1})} = {0.5(\frac{c}{b_1}+b_{1})} = {0.5(\sqrt{c}+b_{1})}  $$

But for me it seems to go nowhere :/

Can somebody help me? :)

Comment: You have applied the base case correctly for $a_1$. For $b_1$, note that $b_1 = \dfrac{a_0 + b_0}{2} \geq \sqrt{a_0 b_0} \geq \sqrt{c}$. Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: thanks! :) But how can I show the inductive step? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: How is $a_n$ defined?  It's not written in the question.

Comment: Now I added it to the question, thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean $a_n = c/b_n$? You have $c/b_1$.

Comment: Oh sry, yeah I actually meant c/bn

Comment: @Blue2001 For the inductive step you can use exactly the same steps you used for the base case. Note that $a_n = \dfrac{c}{b_n} \leq \dfrac{2c}{a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}} \leq \dots$ and $b_n = \dfrac{b_{n-1} + a_{n-1}}{2} \geq \dots $. Can you complete it using these hints?

Comment: But where do I use the proposition?

Comment: I have: $ a_{n+1}  $

Comment: I have: $ a_{n+1} =\frac{c}{b_{n+1}} < \frac{c}{\sqrt{c}} =\sqrt{c} = \sqrt{a_{n}b_{n}} < \frac{a_{n}+b_{n}{2} = b_{n+1} $

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your question. First, you should require $b \gt 0$ and $c \ge 0$ for it to work properly (e.g., if $c \lt 0$, then $\sqrt{c}$ is not even a real number). Second, your $\lt$ should be $\le$, e.g., if $b = c = 1$. Third, what you want to prove for "all integers $n$" should be for positive integers $n$ since your relation doesn't necessarily hold for $n = 0$ (e.g., $b = 1$ and $c = 2$).

This means you want to prove that for all integers $n \ge 1$ that

$$a_n \le \sqrt{c} \le b_n \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note you can prove this directly. However, to do it using induction, start with your base case of $n = 1$. As you stated, using the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) gives

$$b_1 = \frac{a_{0} + b_{0}}{2} \ge \sqrt{a_{0}b_{0}} = \sqrt{c} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using $a_1 = \frac{c}{b_1} \implies a_1 b_1 = c$ and multiplying both sides above by $a_1$ (note $a_1 \ge 0$ so the inequality doesn't change) gives, for $c \gt 0$, that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_1 b_1 & \ge a_1\sqrt{c} \\
c & \ge a_1\sqrt{c} \\
\sqrt{c} & \ge a_1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note if $c = 0$, then $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$ so \eqref{eq3A} (and \eqref{eq5A} below) still hold. This confirms the base case.

For the inductive step, assume \eqref{eq1A} is true for $n = k$ for some integer $k \ge 1$. Since $a_k b_k = c$, using the AM-GM inequality again gives, similar to \eqref{eq2A},

$$b_{k+1} = \frac{a_{k} + b_{k}}{2} \ge \sqrt{a_{k}b_{k}} = \sqrt{c} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Basically repeating the procedure used with \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_{k+1}b_{k+1} & \ge a_{k+1}\sqrt{c} \\
c & \ge a_{k+1}\sqrt{c} \\
\sqrt{c} & \ge a_{k+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This shows \eqref{eq1A} is also true for $n = k + 1$ so, by induction, it's true for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: a) In your equation (3) or (5) really only one line is needed; b) Your induction step is not really an induction step because nowhere did you utilize the fact that $a_k\le \sqrt{c} \le b_k$. BTW, it's not you, it's just that the problem is not a good example for induction at all.

Comment: @NeatMath Thanks for the feedback, and I agree with what you wrote. As I stated in my answer, this can be solved directly. However, since the question asked for doing this using induction, I showed how to go through the steps of the induction procedure, even though I never actually used the induction step aspect of $a_k \le \sqrt{c} \le b_k$.

Comment: Ok thank very much! :) 
How can I show that $ b_{n+1} < b_n and a_{n+1} > a_n $ ? 
I am stuck on this too :/

Comment: @Blue2001 You're welcome. You have $a_{n} \le b_{n} \implies a_{n} + b_{n} \le 2b_{n}$, then $b_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n} + b_{n}}{2} \le b_{n}$. From this, $\frac{1}{b_{n+1}} \ge \frac{1}{b_{n}} \implies \frac{c}{b_{n+1}} \ge \frac{c}{b_{n}} \implies a_{n+1} \ge a_{n}$.